# ESXi 3.5 Corrupted (flat & delta) vmdk files

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-esxi, virtualization, data-recovery, vmfs

Today, I found that one of my VM hosted in ESXi 3.5 cannot be started, the error in /var/log/messages was

```
Mar 14 00:56:21 vmkernel: hda: dma_intr: status=0x51 { DriveReady SeekComplete Error } 
Mar 14 00:56:21 vmkernel: hda: dma_intr: error=0x40 { UncorrectableError }, LBAsect=3861848, high=0, low=3861848, sector=3861841 
Mar 14 00:56:21 vmkernel: 0:01:22:52.747 cpu2:1026)LinBlock: 1926: I/O error, dev 03:00 (hda), sector 3861841 
Mar 14 00:56:21 vmkernel: 0:01:22:52.763 cpu2:1150)StorageMonitor: 196: vmhba1:0:0:0 status = D:0x0/H:0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0 
Mar 14 00:56:21 vmkernel: 0:01:22:52.763 cpu2:1150)SCSI: 4863: path vmhba1:0:0: Forcing host status TIMEOUT to NO_CONNECT 
Mar 14 00:56:21 Hostd: [2011-03-14 00:56:21.375 'BaseLibs' 81926 info] DISKLIB-LIB   : RWv failed ioId: #12386 (327689) (9) . 
Mar 14 00:56:21 Hostd: [2011-03-14 00:56:21.375 'BaseLibs' 81926 warning] [NFC ERROR] Read failed curSector = 6232064, nSectors = 512 :An error was detected (327689). 
Mar 14 00:56:21 Hostd: [2011-03-14 00:56:21.375 'BaseLibs' 81926 warning] [NFC ERROR] NfcFile_ContinueSend: read failed 
Mar 14 00:56:21 vmkernel: 0:01:22:52.803 cpu0:1370)DevFS: 2307: Unable to find device: 2c75e-VM-000001-delta.vmdk
```

I try to copy both -delta.vmdk and -flat.vmdk using cp command, but stil got error

```
cp: Read Error: Input/output error
cp: Write Error: No space left on device
```

It seems the VMFS was corrupted, but I cannot figure-it how to recover this VM.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Restore from last backup?

Comment: no backup unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I connect my hdd into Windows system, and run HDD Regenerator. It move data from bad cluster into the good one. Saved my data. A very good software :D

Comment: be sure to mark this answer as the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hard disk is having a hard time. Try `fsck`to check/repair the disk, but it isn't looking to good for you if you haven't got any backups.